# jquery mobile, correct way to do ajax on nav with .live() or .bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have a navigation bar like this

```
      <div id="top" data-role="navbar" data-type="horizontal">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And I have a `<div id="content">` for example

Then I add my javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
$('div[id="top"] ul li a').live("click", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = //SOME HTML
    var content = $('div[id="content"]');
    $(content).html(html);
});
</script>
```

However, It only works i.e. change the div content to my HTML if I click twice to the button, if I click one It only give me the default page. Any idea how to correct it ?

I create a fiddle here for you to test
http://jsfiddle.net/3Rcem/

I find a solution to use .click() instead of .live('click') but with this I cannot bind to the 'vclick' which is suggested by Jquery mobile, anyone can help me with using live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I changed `.live("click",` to `.click(` it worked fine.

BTW this: `$('div[id="content"]')` is not right. You should do `$('div#content')` and probably just `$('#content')`.

Also this: `<script language="javascript">` is not correct, it should be: `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: my mistakes... it really does work ! Thanks !... any idea why ?

Comment: @iKid It's because you can't use `stopPropagation()` with live events. The docs http://api.jquery.com/live/ suggest returning false so try that. However there does not seem to be a way to `preventDefault()`, so the anchor tag does its thing and overwrites your content (that's also why the suggestion to change it to just '#' worked). I would suggest either contacting jQuery and asking them, or asking a new stackoverflow question specifically about `live()` and `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I also try "return false" without success

Comment: @iKid I know, because return false replaces `stopPropagation()`, but you need something for `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I am displaying now the title as data, but you can change behavior to match your needs. Hope this helps!

```
...
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#top').find('a').click(function(e) {
                var html = "<p>" + $(this).text() + "</p>";
                var content = $('#middle');
                content.html(html);
                return false;
            });        
        });
    </script>  
</head>
```

Comment: maybe you try to copy it to an html file and see, it doesn't work

Comment: yeah, thanks... the problem is with 'live', because you and @Ariel gave the same answer I will give correct to who can explain why it works...

Comment: Try it now, what I added there is script block to the <head> section and also document ready event

Comment: just try still the same ? I do not see any block in head maybe you haven't update your post..

Comment: it should be updated. I tried other browser also. Just to make sure I updated my answer with the code block

Comment: is this the link ? http://jsfiddle.net/ttamminen/Kb8gN/7/ ... I can't see it in there

Comment: It seems that I don't know how to use jsFiddle, so I'll just remove the link. Add the script block to your html file before head and it should work then

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. All I did was change the href's to remove the extra nav part. (e.g. from #A to #).

```
        <header data-role="header" class="ui-bar">   
            <h1> HEADER </h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
            <div id="top" data-role="navbar" data-type="horizontal">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>             
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>   

        <div data-role="content" id="middle">   
            <strong>Content</strong> Is <i>Here</i>
        </div>  

        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">  
            <h1> Copyright (C) by me </h1>
        </footer>  
    </div>  
    <script language="javascript">
        $('div[id="top"] ul li a').live("click", function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var html = $(this).html();
        var content = $('div[id="middle"]');
        $(content).html(html);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah.. it works this way for me too, but I want to refer to the page by using the # as indicator... I don't know why jquery mobile does that, planning to switch to other mobile framework soon